# How can I target a specific node?

Tags: javascript, nodes, line-breaks

My setup is below.

It is working, I just have a small issue with it. Currently its checking for child notes that are text (node.nodeType === 3). The problem is, sometimes there are f.e. links or the text is strong in the paragraph and they are getting removed too.

Basically what I want to do is: target (count) everything in a paragraph that is NOT a break. Or in other words something like this: if(node.nodeType !== br)

An example would look something like this:

```
<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br>
  <strong>
  "Text2"
```

Currently the script would look at the 3 elements between the two texts and would remove the strong  element from Text2 but that is not something I want. It should only count the paragraphs and nothing else.

What can I try next?

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 468px)')
// Check if the media query is true
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

paragraphs.forEach( elem => {
  const nodes = [...elem.childNodes];
  nodes.reduce((count, node) => {
    if(node.nodeType === 3) {
      const isEmpty = node.nodeValue.trim().length === 0;
      return isEmpty ? count : 0; 
    }
    count++;
    if (count>2) node.remove();
    return count;
  }, 0);
});
  
}
```

Comment: Could you add to your question an example of the input, and an example of the output?

Comment: Well if you want to test for `<br>` elements, why not just do that? [`node.nodeName != 'BR'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)

Comment: Why do you use `reduce` if you don't do anything with the return value?

Comment: @Djave I have added an example in the description

Comment: what are we counting? number of characters or number or linebreaks?

Comment: Can you show the output of the function with that example? Should it return `<p>
  "Text"
  <br>
  <br>
  "Text2"`?

Comment: @Djave Exactly how you wrote it. But I want to output everything because there are only 2 breaks and not three, but it detects the strong tag as a break too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to count all elements that aren't a break, you are nearly there, although it looks as if there is a lot of additional code in your example that isn't required.

`nodeName` is the one you want to use to check if something is a br. This is an uppercase version of the tag, so a `<br/>` has a `nodeName` of `BR`.

If I was going to count everything in a paragraph that isn't a `<br/>` I'd do the following:

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");

let count = 0;
paragraphs.forEach( para => {
  const nodes = [...para.childNodes];
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    if(node.nodeName != "BR"){
      count ++;
    }
  })
});

console.log(count);
```

```html
<p>
  text
  <br>
  <br>
  hello world!
  <strong>this is bold</strong>
  yeah yeah
  whatever :)
  <span>something else</span>
</p>
```

I think I'm answering your question, but let me know if not.